# Magento 2: How to Change Default Attribute Set & Set Our Own

Tags: magento2, product, attribute-set

I have created my Attribute Set. Now all current & future  products belongs to that Attribute Set Only.

So i want to set my "Attribute Set" as Default. Instead of Magento Default Attribute Set.

So when i'm going to Add New Product it will be Automatically Selected with my Attributes loaded.
[image]

Comment: Also interested to see if there's an answer to this...

Answer (score 8):

1.Find id of "Attribute Set" in database column `eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id`

2.`` UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `default_attribute_set_id` = ' ``%YOUR_Attribute_Set_ID%`` ' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product'; ``

3. reindex and clear cache

Comment: Thank you Magentobro :) And don't be sad, you're the man !

Comment: @SadMagento Thanks bro! you made my day.

Comment: Just to point no reindex needed, clearing cache is enough

Answer (score 1):

Here is the php way to do it (and yes, I know you shouldn't use the objectmanager but I'm not going to explain that here).  I'm making a one-off script that cleans up the mess from the migration thing.  The code below removes the 'Migration_' attribute codes and assigns the lower values originally used, as well as deleting the new defaults.  You can use this code as you see fit.  The important part is calling the `clear()` function so magento doesn't use values from memory instead of reading your changes to the database.

```
<?php
echo "RUNNING";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$scb = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
$typeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type');
$modelConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$eavConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
$eavSetup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');

$filter = $scb->addFilter('attribute_set_id',null,'neq')->create();
$list = $eavConfig->getList($filter)->getItems();

foreach ($list as $item) {
    $attributeSetName = $item->getAttributeSetName();
    $newItemName = explode('Migration_', $attributeSetName);
    if (is_array($newItemName) && count($newItemName) > 1) {
        $newItemName = $newItemName[1];
        if (strpos($item->getAttributeSetName(), 'Migration') !== false) {
            // See if attribute set name exists already
            // If yes
            // See if the attribute set ID is higher or lower
            // If lower, delete this one
            // If higher, delete found one and save this one.
            // If No
            // Save attribute set without "Migration_"
            foreach ($list as $innerItem) {
                if ($item != $innerItem) {
                    $innerAttributeSetName = $innerItem->getAttributeSetName();
                    if ($newItemName == $innerAttributeSetName && $innerItem->getEntityTypeId() == $item->getEntityTypeId()) {
                        if ($innerItem->getAttributeSetId() > $item->getAttributeSetId()) {
                            $type = $typeConfig->load($item->getEntityTypeId())
                                ->setData('default_attribute_set_id', $item->getAttributeSetId())
                                ->save();

                            $modelConfig->clear();
                            $resource = $innerItem->getResource();
                            $resource->delete($innerItem);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            $item->setName($newItemName);
            $item->save();
        }
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: thanks @CarComp - based off your script, I put up a quick module (didn't end up using much from your script other than the initial thought process) https://github.com/treestonemedia/postmigartion-magento-cleanup

Comment: Thats all i ever intended. Thanks for your contributions!